# Async/Await is still blocking the UI?

Tags: multithreading, async-await, task

Not super familiar with Async/Await, but have this snippet of code, and it still blocks the UI when it's called? I just get the 'waiting' cursor, can't move the window, etc.

```
    Public Async Function IsPortReachable(ByVal strHost As String, Optional ByVal intPort As Integer = 80, Optional ByVal intTimeoutMs As Integer = 5000) As Task(Of Boolean)

        ' Throw an exception if no host was passed
        If String.IsNullOrEmpty(strHost) Then Throw New ArgumentNullException(NameOf(strHost))

        Return Await Task.Run(Function()

                                  Dim clientDone As ManualResetEvent = New ManualResetEvent(False)
                                  Dim bReachable As Boolean = False
                                  Dim hostEntry As DnsEndPoint = New DnsEndPoint(strHost, intPort)

                                  Using socket = New Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp)

                                      Dim socketEventArg = New SocketAsyncEventArgs With {.RemoteEndPoint = hostEntry}

                                      AddHandler socketEventArg.Completed, Sub(s, e)
                                                                               bReachable = e.SocketError = SocketError.Success
                                                                               clientDone.Set()
                                                                           End Sub

                                      clientDone.Reset()
                                      socket.ConnectAsync(socketEventArg)
                                      clientDone.WaitOne(intTimeoutMs)

                                      Return bReachable

                                  End Using

                              End Function).ConfigureAwait(False)
    End Function
```

And I call it from the main form like this, which also happens on `Form_Load`, so there's an unwanted delay before the user is able to 'take back control' of the program:

```
Dim bTask As Task(Of Boolean) = IsPortReachable(dicValidated.Item("DNS2Up"), Convert.ToInt32(dicValidated.Item("DNS2UpPort")), 1000)
```

I was under the impression that Async/Await functions ran on a different thread, leaving the calling thread (the UI thread) free of blocking?

Comment: Don't use `.ConfigureAwait` UI code.

Comment: Your code will be easier to read if you move your inner Task function (with `Dim clientDone...`) to its own top-level function, btw.

Comment: Is there a reason you're using the non-Async Socket API?

Comment: Async does not create threads. It is the opposite: it allows multiple tasks to share a thread. If it always created threads, then we wouldn't need to invent Async. We would just use threads.

Answer (score 0):

Calling an async method does not start or use different thread nor makes execution of that method asynchronous just that. Only at the first occurrence of an await operation within that method yields the execution back to the caller and hooks up an asynchronous continuation to run the rest of that method later, asynchronously (there is one exception, but keep it simple for now).

But even that continuation may runs on the calling thread, especially if there is a synchronization context involved, like in case of using WinForms or WPF. It can lead to deadlock, but you solved it already by adding `ConfigureAwait(false)`.

If I understand right, (and the code suggests the same), there is no deadlock in your code, you only experience a "short" unresponsiveness in the UI. I suspect you call `bTask.Result` in `Form_Load` function later, what blocks the UI thread up until `IsPortReachable` finishes its job. Changing this blocking code to `await bTask` should solve your problem.

Side note: I would also refrain from using ManualResetEvent and call `socket.ConnectAsync()` using await. This case you could get rid of `Task.Run(...)` too.